# temperatures of metal facing the sun in space

Tags: physics, thermal

If a piece of metal were orbiting the Sun at the distance from earth to Mars, always facing the sun, what would it's temperature be.

Comment: Is it shiny and smooth or rough and dark?

Comment: Perfectly clean or oxidized? The problem is that an emissivity is needed for visible light and for thermal IR. Also, without any more context, this is really purely a physics question and not specific to Space Exploration.

Comment: Copper or gold or alumin or silver, that would result in a different temperature.

Comment: This is actually a complex problem. As already commented, the precise composition of the metal is very important. In some cases, relatively minor constituents of an alloy can make a big difference. Other factors: the albedo and emissivities of the surfaces (ex: oxidized or not, coated or not) both front and back, and if it's very thick, the sides as well; and the *thickness* of the metal, since that establishes the net thermal conductivity to the back side, which radiates heat to space. Also I'm unsure what you mean by "...at the distance from earth to Mars..."

Comment: This is a very vague question.  You haven't even defined its orbital radius in a clear manner.

Comment: The reason that I asked that question was that I am designing a spacecraft. A cargo spacecraft, no crew to make trips to and from Mars cheaply. But the metal must heat up and then use the heat to propel the ship through space. It is not a fast ship but it will get there and back cheaply.
I keep running into problems that space is very cold that far from the sun. If the metal doesn't heat up hot then it can't transfer the heat to the fuel and the spacecraft won't move.

Comment: @tajs Welcome to Stack Exchange! That's a much clearer explanation than what you originally posted. Your original question is pretty vague and so it attracted many down votes. It's sometimes hard to figure out SE when starting, but the more specific your question is, the easier it is to answer and the more likely it will be to get a good answer and a positive reception. I'd normally recommend you rewrite your question based on that comment, but there's already a lengthy answer posted so it's not good to modify your question too much. Instead, why not post *a new more specific question?*

Comment: @tajs I think what you are describing is a [solar thermal rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_thermal_rocket). If so, then you can even mention that in your title of your next question. Including a link in your question shows you've done a bit of research first before asking, and that also usually helps your question receive a positive response from other users. Finally, if you can check back more than once a day to respond to comments, thought not required, it can help. Thanks!

Comment: Okay folks 6 down votes on a new user's first question is enough perhaps?

Comment: Much more efficient than heating is to deploy a solar sail.  You'll get a lot more thrust that way.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft higher Isp, sure, but higher thrust? You'd need either a pretty rubbish solar thermal rocket, or an immense sail. The solar thermal design should be much more compact, and a much easier engineering challenge.

Answer (score 16):

A single number is impossible to give, unless you *exactly* specify the kind of metal. So I'll answer in the general sense.

The first question to answer is "*How much energy does the sheet absorb?*". This is given by the **Inverse-Square Law**:

$$ I={\frac {P}{A}}={\frac {P}{4\pi r^{2}}}$$

For Mars, this works out to $~ 589\frac W {m^2}$ of energy.

The next thing we need to consider is what happens with the energy that the metal sheet absorbs? If it just absorbed the energy, it would get hotter and hotter, melt, then turn into a plasma and at some point leave the realm of physics. What happens is that the metal needs to shed energy/heat. The three principal mechanisms of heat transfer are

- convection (transfer of heat in gases and fluids)
- conduction (transfer of heat between touching solid objects)
- radiation (transfer of heat via thermal radiation)

Obviously, only the third option is available to our sheet of metal. So basically, emission (how much energy is radiated away) and absorption of energy must be equal. Lets call the emitted energy $\Phi_e$ and the absorbed energy $\Phi_a$, then we can state this formally as:

$$\Phi_e = \Phi_a$$

> This radiation equilibrium between emitted radiation and absorbed radiation basically applies to every body in thermal equilibrium, including non-ideal black bodies that do not radiate at maximum power. After all, a constant temperature and thus a thermal equilibrium will be reached for every object after a certain time, in which emission and absorption must take place to the same extent. This law is also called *Kirchhoff’s law of radiation*. ([Source](https://www.tec-science.com/thermodynamics/temperature/stefan-boltzmann-law/#Real_bodies)).

The unfortunate thing is that we don't know $\Phi_a$ yet. Materials have properties, and three important ones are the *spectral absorption component $\alpha$* (Absorption), the *spectral reflection component $\rho$* (Reflectance) and the *spectral transmission component* $\tau$ (Transmittance).

> When radiant energy reaches a surface, the energy can be absorbed, transmitted (through), or reflected (or any combination). The sum of these three effects equals the total energy transmitted, and the parameters that describe these three phenomena are given by
> $$\alpha + \rho + \tau = 1$$
> ([Source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/thermal-radiation))

So if we know the properties of the material, especially absorption rates, we can calculate how much of the $589 \frac W {m^2}$ our sheet of metal absorbs!

But we still don't know how hot it becomes. But there is a law for that as well:

> The radiative heat transfer rate is given by the Stefan-Boltzmann law
>
> $$Q_T = \sigma A T^4$$
>
> where σ is the Boltzmann constant and A is the surface area of the radiating source. The temperature is in an absolute scale (°Kelvin, corresponding to °C, or °Rankin, corresponding to °F)

However, this applies to a perfect black body. Our metal is not. We still need another thing:

> In purely formal terms, the emission power of a real body can also be expressed with a factor which then indicates the ratio of the emitted radiation of the real body compared to an ideal black body! This factor is referred to as emissivity ε. ([Source](https://www.tec-science.com/thermodynamics/temperature/stefan-boltzmann-law/#Real_bodies))

Plugging this together, we end up with

$$\Phi_{e,real} = \varepsilon \cdot \sigma \cdot A \cdot T^4 $$

And that has to equal $\Phi_a$.

Note, however, that if you consider your metal sheet to be a plane, you absorb only on one side and emit on two sides. Hence you get a 1:2 ratio between the absorbing and emitting area, which you need to account for.

<sub>Furthermore, if the thickness of the metal becomes non-negligible, you need to consider all 6 sides. But other than the ratio, the areas cancel out in this formula.</sub>

**So, if you decide what properties the metal sheet has (especially emissivity and absorption rate), you can plug in the numbers here and find out how hot the metal becomes, everywhere in space, not only in Mars orbit.**

---

Things I deliberately glossed over:

- out-gassing or loss of mass in general
- not being in a perfect vacuum (interaction with other particles)
- other sources of radiation, especially interstellar radiation
- non-uniformity of the heat distribution
- and probably a few other things...

---

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/thermal-radiation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law#Light_and_other_electromagnetic_radiation
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/radiative-heat-transfer
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/boltzmann-constant
- https://www.tec-science.com/thermodynamics/temperature/stefan-boltzmann-law/#Real_bodies

Comment: The cube (and other 3D geometries) gets complex. This is a class of problem my thermal-systems colleagues at JPL commonly face. Of course the sun-facing side is the hottest, but though the other five sides are equal in area to the sun-facing one, their temperatures are not uniform — nor is the temperature of the sun-facing side uniform! The temperature of any given spot on the unilluminated surface is a complex interaction of radiation from that spot and conduction from (and to!) the 2pi steradians of metal around that point. Edges are special (1pi), and corners even more so (pi/2).